# How can I determine the original dataset of an observation after rbind?

Tags: r, dataset, rbind

I have 113 different datasets and use the R-command "rbind" to put them into one single dataset. Now my question: How can I determine from which original dataset a specific observation stems? Is there any command in R for that? I use the following reading loop:

```
read_data <- function(directory,debug=FALSE){
  file_list = list.files(path = directory,
                       pattern = "*.csv",
                       full.names = TRUE);

  df_read = data.frame();

  for (filename in file_list){
    df_temp = read_delim(filename,
                      delim=';',
                      locale = locale(encoding = "latin1"));

    if(debug){
      print(paste0(c(filename, " : ", dim(df_temp))));  
    }

    df_read = rbind(df_read, df_temp);

  }

  names(df_read) = make.names(names(df_read))

  return(df_read)
}


df1    = read_data("path")
df2    = read_data("path")
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
# Read in the other data and compare the price data to it: 

# a) store a vector that's values are the relative file path: 

file_list <- as.character(list.files(path = directory, pattern = "*.csv", full.names = TRUE))

# b) Allocate memory for a list vector the length of the file names: 

df_list <- vector("list", length(file_list))

# c) read every .csv and store it as an element in the list: 

df_list <- lapply(seq_along(file_list),

                  function(x){read_delim(x, delim = ';', locale = locale(encoding = "latin1"))})

# d) Name each element in the list appropriately: 

names(df_list) <- gsub('.*[/]', '', file_list)

# e) Convert all cleaned data to it's appropraite type: 

df_list <- lapply(df_list, type.convert)

# f) Add a column that's value is the name of the sheet: 

df_list <- mapply(cbind, "file_name" = names(df_list), df_list, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

# !! ASSUMING ALL THE FILE COLUMNS ARE THE SAME: 
# g) Row bind the dataframes together:

df_with_names <- do.call("rbind", df_list)
```

!!ASSUMING NOT ALL COLUMNS ARE THE SAME:

```
# g) Perform a full outer join on each of the sheets: 

df_with_names <- Reduce(function(x, y){

  merge(x, y, all = TRUE,  by = intersect(colnames(x), colnames(y)))},

  df_list)
```